# Is there anything obviously wrong with this hit test code?

Tags: arcobjects

I want to know if the IPoint of the mouse position is hitting an IPolyline, I wrote this code, and was optimistic that it would work, but it always returns false.

```
  IPolyline poly1 = pc1 as IPolyline;

        IHitTest test = poly1 as IHitTest;
        if (test != null)
        {
            int a = 0;
            int b = 0;
            bool c = false;
            double distance = 0;
            IPoint hitPoint = new PointClass();
            bool isHit = test.HitTest(mousepoint,
                                    50000,
                                    esriGeometryHitPartType.esriGeometryPartNone,
                                    hitPoint,
                                    ref distance,
                                    ref a, ref b, ref c);


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should probably not use `esriGeometryHitPartType.esriGeometryPartNone`, but choose a geometry part which you want to test.

In your case that would probably be `esriGeometryHitPartType.esriGeometryPartBoundary`, which means anywhere on the polyline.